# PayPal IPN - Make the script secure

Tags: php, security, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an IPN script which is inside **ipn.php** on the `root` folder. Inside it I pretty much check all the stuff I need to make it as much secure as I could:

- I check if `TXN_ID` was already been processed.
- I check if `payment_status` is Completed.
- I check if `receiver_email` is the correct one.
- I check if `payment_currency` is the correct one.
- I check if `item_number` and `custom` haven't been edited manually by the user.

Are there any other ways to make it more secure? Can I put **ipn.php** inside a folder which deny access from all through `.htaccess` and make it works somehow? Or maybe I just need to rename **ipn.php** to something like **ipn_40kdizksAoSka.php**?

Comment: i think you done enough and also better change IPN file name

Comment: I found this FAQ on paypal-knowledge.com. 

How do I modify Apache mod_security to accept incoming IPN requests?
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1391&expand=true&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do suggest you rename the file to something more complex as the file name ipn.php is very commonly used. Depending on how your script works, you can also change it's permissions so it's only readable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

set a custom get parameter then test for it within your ipn.php, e.g.,
http://domain.com/ipn.php?secret=Spaceships_RANDOM_STRING_1235325346

be sure to update your notifyURL